# Folding/Rolling-up boxes in MediaWiki

Tags: html, mediawiki

In MediaWiki, if the Index at the top is large, it becomes show/hideable.

Is there a way to do this with other sections in MediaWiki?

I maintain technical documentation on an internal wiki, and I would like to be able to hide some documentation that 99% of users won't need:

```
Before installing Massive Application, install the JDK [show+]
```

Clicking on "Show+" would unroll a `<pre>` box with the instructions in.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since v1.18, out-of-the-box you can do the following (as described [here](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aNavFrame)):

```
<div class="mw-collapsible mw-collapsed">
This text is not collapsible; but the next is collapsible and
hidden by default:
<div class="mw-collapsible-content">{{Lorem}}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Of course, the other answer I provided is applicable for wikis that are using versions before MediaWiki 1.18.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible, but requires some addition into the MediaWiki:Common.js file in your wiki. Such functionality is already live on the [English Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org).

Take a look at [Wikipedia:NavFrame](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia%3aNavFrame) for documentation about the usage and to see how to implement it on another wiki (like yours).